# Open Uber App with pre-selected destination from web view

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I am wondering if it is possible to open the Uber App with a preselected destination from a `UIWebView`.
I actually have a website that offers me the possibility to select a destination address, then I would like to create a link on this website, that can be clickable from a `UIWebPage` and which would open Uber App with the destination address pre-selected.

I don't know if there is an easy way to do so. Otherwise, I will try to play with Uber SDK.

**EDIT**

It's possible to open Uber App with a URL scheme like that :

```
NSURL* uberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"uber://"];
```

But I still don't know if we can preselect a destination.

Comment: It is only possible if Uber app has open `URL Scheme` and it supports such handling, else you can't do this.

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. The thing I do manage to do is to pre-select a destination.

Comment: Yes Uber does have URL Scheme, and good support too [see this](https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking-action-setpickup), it has all defined parameters you can pass from web.

Comment: Really nice, thank you @iphonic